# MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

When ever i try to insert  a new record i am getting the forrlowing error and actually username is itself not part of my model but i am not sure why i am getting this error,can anyone guess the error please.

My error,

```
MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: project1.students.$username_1  dup key: { : null }
```

My collection,

```
 var StudentSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, default: '' },
  first_name: { type: String, default: '' },
  last_name: { type: String, default: '' },
  email: { type: String, default: '' },
  display_name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    validate: [validateUsername, 'Please enter a valid username: 3+ characters long, non restricted word, characters "_-.", no consecutive dots, does not begin or end with dots, letters a-z and numbers 0-9.'],
    lowercase: true,
    trim: true
  },
 });
```

My indexes,

```
 [
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "project1.students"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "username" : 1
        },
        "name" : "username_1",
        "ns" : "project1.students",
        "background" : true
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your username is indexed and hence whenever you try to insert a doc with the same username this error comes. Indexes should be unique.And if username is not a part of your model can you please tell your models schema.

Comment: in my model i dont have any username field

Comment: can you tell me what exactly is your collection and what are you sending?

Comment: edited my code.

Comment: Pls check which fileds are indexed using this-> db.getCollection('students').getIndexes();

Comment: Riya,can you see my edited code.

Comment: yeah your username is also indexed so pls drop that using-> db.students.dropIndex( "username_1")

Comment: Funtastic......mindblowing............unbelievable....:) Thanks

Comment: But one doubht.....i removed it in my db@RoboMOngo is there any scope for removing it from my folder...so that i can commit code and the rest cannot face the same issue.

Comment: now there will be no issues as robomongo is just a client for mongodb. So, if you have dropped the index there won't be any issue.

Comment: In production also if i do the same ...its clear?

Comment: yeah drop the index from the server where mongodb is hosted.